# Концепцию можно... исполнить?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> Однако сама концепция оформления источника, исполненная Паоло Беналья,
>   – отвергнута.

Тире можно пережить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Однако сама концепция оформления источника, исполненная Паоло Беналья, ― отвергнута.**

А почему бы и нет?  Концепция художественного оформления ― это разработанная в деталях идея, а **идею можно исполнить**.

Мы привыкли к тому, что обычно исполняют роль, музыку, танец, но **художественное произведение тоже исполняют**, например: Пожалуй, единственной вещью, контрастирующей с общим настроением выставки, была **карикатура** на московского генерал-губернатора, **исполненная в 1880-е годы.** [Екатерина Зайцева. Владимир Московское Солнышко // «Родина», 2010]

А это пример из области оформления помещения: ... есть и другие прекрасные концептуальные и жанровые **идеи,** виртуозно **исполненные** известными российскими рестораторами.

Поэтому, возможно,  Паоло Беналья **исполнил эскизы** оформления источника, которые и были отвергнуты.

Из словаря: **ИСПОЛНИТ**Ь, 3. обычно страд. прич. прош. **Создать, сделать, выполнить.** Хорошо исполненная фотография. **КОНЦЕПЦИЯ**,  2. Основная мысль, идея произведения, сочинения и т.п.

2) **Тире здесь авторское**, соответствует паузе в устной речи. В этом случае логически выделяется первая часть высказывания. Часто авторского тире связано с  содержанием контекста,  а не только одного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вряд ли "*исполненная концепция*" - удачное словосочетание: "исполнение" предполагает осуществление задания или замысла в соответсвии с *конкретными* требованиями или планами относительно формы, в то время как "концепции" свойственны лишь общие черты (т. е. относительно высокий уровень абстрагирования), приблизительность. Концепции при осуществлении замысла обычно **следуют** или её **придерживаются**; ещё её можно **осуществить** в некоторой форме, за которой её не сразу и не всякий разглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Источник — объёмное инженерное сооружение, требующее разработки проекта, а также монументального оформления. Проекту оформления в объёме часто предшествует выполнение рисунков на плоскости и необходимых деталей в объёме, объединённых текстом, что и называют концепцией.

Выполнить — более подходящее слово. Но, если придерживаться того, что есть, можно сказать так: «Однако сама концепция оформления источника в исполнении Паоло Беналья, — отвергнута». Где тире стоит вместо «была».

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже кажется, что концепцию не исполняют, а разрабатывают, создают.

Однако сама концепция оформления источника, **разработанная** Паоло Беналья, – отвергнута.

Тире интонационное, по-моему, на месте: расчленяет предложение на 2 части для облегчения восприятия и подчёркивания сказуемого. Это авторский знак, факультативный, но он возможен.

Answer (score 0):

Одну концепцию можно воплотить, реализовать различными способами. Отношение "один ко многим".

Исполнить можно, например, приказ. Отношение "один к одному". Исполнение приказов фантазий не подразумевает :).

Comment: Тебя там встретит огнегривый лев
и синий вол исполненный очей...